# Is there any research work on known malware detection systems based on AI?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, reference-request, ai-security

I'm working on writing an article about the possibilities of modern AI-based algorithms to produce invisible self-learning malware, that can distribute itself throughout the internet and create flexible botnets.

So far, I can not find any additional information about that, except [this one](https://www.fanaticalfuturist.com/2018/08/ibm-created-an-undetectable-cyberweapon-by-injecting-viruses-into-neural-nets/).

Is there any research work on known malware detection systems based on AI?

Comment: Hello. It seemed to me that you were only interested in "neural networks" (and not every possible "AI technique"), so I edited your post to reflect that. If that assumption/supposition was incorrect, feel free to edit your post and clarify your question again. Moreover, can you clarify what you mean by "self-learning malware"? Do you mean NNs that can detect malwares, right?

Comment: @nbro: My interpretation of OP's question before you edited it, is that they are looking for research about creating malware, and the detection part is about whether anyone has seen real world evidence that AI-created malware is in the wild. Whilst the linked article is about using AI systems for smart deployment of software payloads that would be very difficult to analyse without valid trigger input.

Comment: @NeilSlater The original question was "May be anyone can help me to find any information about known detections of malware based on AI?", so it seems that the current question is at least consistent with the original question. It's also true that this post wasn't fully clear, so I don't exclude that you may be right and the OP simply didn't formulate the question very clearly. Only the OP can confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for editing your post and clarifying that you're interested in any AI technique, but can you clarify this part "to produce invisible self-learning malware"? What do you mean by that? It's not clear what you mean by that because of this part "that can distribute itself throughout the internet and create flexible botnets.", and I think that's why Neil thought the question was another one.